# Is StanfordCoreNLP deprecated?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

In the [documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Usage), there is an example that utilizes the class: `StanfordCoreNLP`. But when you download the latest version, the class is nowhere to be found. It's found easily in earlier versions and the example works great. I've been looking all over but can't seem to figure out what happened to `StanfordCoreNLP`.

Has anyone used recent versions of the library who can tell me what happened to `StanfordCoreNLP`?

Comment: In my opinion, if they meant to deprecate it, they should have used the `@Deprecated` annotation instead of removing the class entirely.

Comment: The class is still in CoreNLP 3.2.0: edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP

Just found it in the CoreNLP 3.2.0 Maven artifact using the Eclipse  "open type" feature - actually making this an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is still in CoreNLP 3.2.0:

```
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
```

Just found it in the CoreNLP 3.2.0 Maven artifact using the Eclipse "open type" feature.

Comment: Oh dang, my maven repo index wasn't up to date, so I wasn't getting the latest indexes. I double checked on Maven central search and there it was. I don't see it in the "full parser package" that is on Stanford's site, but I think it's hitting me that this is a different beast.

Comment: The parser package is a separate thing indeed. While there is pretty much overlap with CoreNLP, there are actually classes in the parser package which are not (yet?) in CoreNLP, e.g. for some foreign language support.

Comment: It does not seem to be in 3.5.0

Comment: According to Maven Central, it's still there in 3.5.0: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP%22%20AND%20v%3A3.5.0